# How to check a Checkboxlist based on given value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Checkboxlist like this

```
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" ForeColor="White" Height="156px"
        Visible="False" Width="106px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Monday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Tuesday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Wednesday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Thursday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">Friday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="6">Saturday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="7">Sunday</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I have retrieved values from the database and I am splitting the values like this

```
    string s = TextBox2.Text;
    string[] values = s.Split(',');
```

For example: if I have 2,3,6 in the textbox, I need to check ListItem 2,3,6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop should work as expected:

```
foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    item.Selected = values.Contains(item.Value);
```